# Loading https page in webview

Tags: android, webview, https, android-webview, webviewclient

I am trying to display `https://plus.google.com/myprofilepage`(ignore myprofilepage part I just made it up, in code its substituted with my actual profile page) page in my app within a `webview`. The problem is the app is not displaying anything, earlier I tried with just `http://www.google.com` and `https://www.google.co.in` and it worked.

There are no logs created, so could not get them. I do have internet connected and AndroidManifest.xml too has permission INTERNET.

I want the google plus page to be displayed in WebView is just my basic requirement, I think I am missing something that is required to load google plus. Can someone help.

`targetsdkversion` is 21.

Below is my code:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about_developer, container, false);
        //String url = getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.about_page);
        String url="https://plus.google.com";
        WebView webView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.devwebView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebviewHandler());
        webView.setInitialScale(1);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
        webView.loadUrl(url);
        return v;
    }

    private class WebviewHandler extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(final WebView view, final SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            handler.proceed();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Google+ uses a lot of javascript, enable it with `webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`. Worked for me

Comment: I had tried it before...I am able to see www.google.com but plus.google.com is not working.

Answer (score 0):

+1 to what Lamorak said. Enabling JavaScript is a must. This is the bare minimum of code that is required (besides having the `INTERNET` permission):

```
WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
// This is to avoid "Open with..." dialog for the G+ page.
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
// Enable JavaScript.
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
// The two lines below are to enable interpreting <meta viewport> tag.
settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.loadUrl("http://plus.google.com/...");
```

Comment: I had tried it before...I am able to see www.google.com but plus.google.com is not working.

Comment: @Ranjith: That's interesting. You can try debugging this. Set up your app so it loads `www.google.com` successfully, then follow the steps from here: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging#debugging-webviews and after you have succeeded in attaching DevTools to your app, open "Console" tab, type `window.location.href='http://plus.google.com/...'` (the url you were trying to use), open "Network" tab in DevTools and check what is happening to your network requests.